# How to continuously monitor the directory using inotifyd on an android device

Tags: android, linux, filesystemwatcher

I need to watch a directory on an android device(e.g /sdcard). I need to log any actions occurred at /sdcard. For example, if an app creates file or directory at /sdcard, I would like to log a name of application and event, that occurred, into a file.

I searched on google about the command to watch a directory. I found that I can use "inotifyd" command. I really do not know how I can use it. I don't find clear an example of how to use this command

Does anyone helps me to understand this command, how does work?

Comment: Bear in mind that this will not be practical on Android Q and higher. I strongly recommend that you come up with some other solution to whatever problem that you are trying to solve this way.

Comment: @CommonsWare What changes in Android Q to make this impractical?

Comment: @aggregate1166877: Apps have [very little access to external or removable storage on Android 10 and higher](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html).

Answer (score 1):

On my phone, inotifyd spits out this usage:

> ```
> usage: inotifyd PROG FILE[:MASK] ...
>
> When a filesystem event matching MASK occurs to a FILE, run PROG as:
>   PROG EVENTS FILE [DIRFILE]
>
> If PROG is "-" events are sent to stdout.
>
> This file is:
>   a  accessed    c  modified    e  metadata change  w  closed (writable)
>   r  opened      D  deleted     M  moved            0  closed (unwritable)
>   u  unmounted   o  overflow    x  unwatchable
>
> A file in this directory is:
>   m  moved in    y  moved out   n  created          d  deleted
>
> When x event happens for all FILEs, inotifyd exits (after waiting for PROG).
> ```

With some testing, I found this to works for me:

```
inotifyd - /sdcard/myfile.txt
```

This will then, for example, spit out `e  /sdcard/myfile.txt` if I run `touch /sdcard/myfile.txt`.

If you want to log the changes to a file instead, you can use:

```
inotifyd - /sdcard/myfile.txt >/sdcard/changes.log 2>&1
```

To instead call a script when changes occur, you can use:

```
inotifyd myscript.sh /sdcard/myfile.txt
```